# Is a marriage valid without providing prior divorce papers?

Tags: sharia

A Muslim lady who was a divorcee married a man without providing her previous divorce papers. Is her marriage OK?

Comment: Did she inform him before he married her that she was a divorcee? Other than that papers are just government formalities.

Comment: In Islamic Jurisprudence you don't need papers to validate your divorce. Both the ex-husband and the husband-to-be have to know that the woman is divorced. Paper work is important if you want to handle things properly, specially related to their property.

Comment: is ir nesassary to give divorce paper  to qazi  at her second nikah

Comment: If papers are not needed, why should it be necessary to show them a qadi? The point that makes divorce take place is simply speaking the end of the 'idah (waiting period) without a reconciliation. Else a marriage would be invalid. This is covered in the given answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some cultures and countries insist on 'paper work'. But like @Noah and @System Down have sated, they are only formalities.

However, whether paper work is there or not, the following need to be done.

1. She must be officially divorced (not pending).
2. Shem must have completed her waiting period (Iddah). No marriage is possible without that.